# Using partial View in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I'm working with a Grid editor and Partial View,but I'm having some trouble because I'm testing everything and I've tried to test what I'm trying to do in JSFiddle and it works the way it was supposed to, but in Umbraco it doesn't work properly. This is what I want to get: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nfds89/co8b5v34/).

```css
.work-item {
    height:300px;
    width:350px;
}

.work-item-image {
    top:0;
}

.work-item-image img {
    max-height: 150px;
    max-width: 350px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.work-item-text {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px 3px 3px 30px;
 height:150px;
    max-height: 150px;
    max-width: 350px;
 background-color:black;
} 

img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.work-item-image:hover {
    background-color: black;
}

.work-item-image:hover img {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.work-item-text:hover {
 background-color:white;
}

.work-item-text-title {
 font-family: verdana; 
    font-size: 20px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    background: #ffffcc;
    color: green; 
    line-height: 18px;
 text-align:center;
}

.work-item-text-description {
 font-family: verdana; 
    font-size: 15px;
    color: green; 
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="work-item">
   <a href="#">
    <div class="work-item-image"> 
     <img src="http://posshop.weebly.com/uploads/4/6/6/5/46650449/s317130528826496337_p7_i1_w1000.jpeg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="work-item-text" height="150" width="350">
     <div class="work-item-text-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla volutpat justo non quam lobortis congue<br></div>
     <div class="work-item-text-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla volutpat justo non quam lobortis congue</div>
    </div>
   </a>
 </div>
```

In JSFiddle it works perfectly, but within Umbraco my text overflows the div, wich mensn that with Umbraco, if the text is longer than one line, it will continue through outside the box in one line only.

I don't think the problem is within the html or the css because it works properly in JSFiddle, so what could it be? Would really appreciate some insights on this!

Thanks in advance, Nelson

Comment: Have you compared the HTML umbraco puts out with the original HTML? Is there any difference?

Comment: Umbraco doesn't ever create its own frontend HTML or styles, so it is NOT an Umbraco issue. I bet the template you use to show your partial view has its own stylesheet which is causing the issue. Have you tried looking in DevTools (typically you can press F12) to see which styles are applied to your divs - and which stylesheet they are coming from.